# Do any scriptures talk about Astradhari Sannyasis?

Tags: war, sanyasi

Sannyasis can be divided into two groups:

• Shastradhari Sannyasis: Ascetics who deal with the study of scriptures.

• Astradhari Sannyasis: Ascetics who deal with warfare.

Astradhari Sannyasis are known to have played a crucial role against Islamic invasion in mediaeval North India.

My question is do any scriptures talk about Sannyasis who actively bear weapons and engage in warfare? Are there examples of renowned Astradhari Sannyasis in any scriptures?

Comment: It was prescribed by Madhusudan Saraswati in 'Rajnam pratibodhah'. Do you consider that to be a scripture?

Comment: Um, I'm actually looking from Puranas, Sannyasa Upanishads and Itihasas. @commonman

Comment: Btw, I don't mean any disrespect to Madhusudan Saraswati. @commonman

Comment: Yes, I also wont include his writing in scrriptures.But the sastras were his introduction by consent of Emperor Akbar.So i think no chance of getting in anynscripture,I may be wrong though

Comment: What a coincidence that I see this today, when I was pondering the contrast of violence and peace earlier in the day. I never knew Shastradhari Sannyasis were a thing. I will have to look it up now. Meanwhile could you link any good material?

Comment: @Weezy I have only this for now: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akhara

Comment: please give scriptural source for your question. i have not heard of this division.

Comment: I don't have a scriptural quote. In fact, my question itself is asking for a scriptural quote.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Hariyana ke vedanta parampara aur baba totapuri by Vaidya Banamali Dutta Sharmaji gives reference of Madhusudan Sarasvati's instruction regarding this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is unlikely that scriptures will allow the concept of a "warrior Sannyasi" because dealing with weapons is mentioned as one of the reasons that brings about a Sannyasi's downfall.

> A full meal given by one person, pride, envy, adorning with perfume
>   and flowers, betel leaves, injunction, amusement, desire for pleasure,
>   elixir, boasting, reviling, imparting blessings, astrology, buying and
>   selling, rites, ritual disputes, violating the commands of the
>   teacher, involvement in quarrels and reconciliations, vehicles,
>   couches, white clothes, masturbation, sleeping during the day, metal
>   begging bowls, poison, weapons, seeds, injuring, fierceness, sexual
>   intercourse, observances, such as those of a householder, which were
>   abandoned through renunciation, all social divisions such as
>   lineage,father's and mother's families, and wealth—these are
>   forbidden. He who resorts to them will sink downward.
>
> **Immovable and movable property, seeds, metal objects, poison, and
>   weapons: these six an ascetic shall refrain from accepting, as he
>   would urine and excrement.**
>
> Outside a time of distress, an ascetic shall never carry any
>   provisions for a journey. During a time of distress when food is
>   unavailable, he may take with him a cooked dish.
>
> *Brihat Sannyasa Upanishad*

From [here](http://merki.lv/vedas/Upanishadas/Sannyasa%20Upanishad%20_eng_.pdf) you can read the Upanishad I am quoting from. Translation is slightly different here and I'm giving it below.

> 109. A wise man, though very old, shall not trust in women though very old. Even in very old patched garments old cloth will stick (when
>        stitched).
> 110. **Immovable property, mobile things (servants), seed (for cultivation), gold, gum-myrrh and weapon these six an ascetic shall
>        not take up as (though they were)
>        urine and faeces.**

Verses are from Adhyaya two of the text.